# python sdist recursive-include folder, where is it once installed?

Tags: python, installation

I have this in my `MANIFEST.in`

```
recursive-include tables *.csv
```

and I can see the folder included in the created `.tar.gz`

```
/mypackage-0.0.1
    /mypackage
    /mypackage.egg-info
    /tables
```

but I can't find my folder once I install the package with:

```
pip install mypackage-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

or

```
easy_install mypackage-0.0.1.tar.gz
```

Any clue?

Answer (score 3):

With MANIFEST.in, you specify the files to embedd in the archive, not the way they will be installed.

To tell python/distutils where you want to install your files, add in your setup.py fill the  parameter `data_files` in the setup() method. This way, you will be able to specify where to install [those additional files](http://docs.python.org/distutils/setupscript.html#distutils-additional-files).

Comment: The bad part with `data_files` is they are installed under `sys.prefix` (usually `/usr`). This can give big troubles if you want to include a folder with a common name, say `share`. I found that moving `tables` under inner `mypackage` to be more consistent and error proof than all I had to do is add files to `MANIFEST.in` (say `tables` files are csv files I just added `*.csv` after `recursive-include mypackage *.txt ...`